# Запись в БД при выборе картинки

Tags: php

На странице есть 2 картинки, если пользователь выбирает первую и нажимает кнопку, в бд должен записаться 0, если вторую, то 1, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, в консоли тоже никакой информации
Вот код:

```
<form method="POST">
   <div class="v_radio">
    <input name="r" id="r1" type="radio">
    <label for="r1">
        <img class="v-r1" src="img/icons/v-id.png">
        <span>Passport</span>
    </label>
    <input name="r" id="r2" type="radio">
    <label for="r2">
        <img class="v-r2" src="img/icons/v-passport--green.png">
        <span>Driver license</span>
    </label>
</div>
<button type="submit">next</button>

</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["r1"])) {
    $filed = 0;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE Verification SET TypeID='$filed' WHERE id='$sesion_id'");
}
if (isset($_POST["r2"])) {
        $filed = 1;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE Verification SET TypeID='$filed' WHERE id='$sesion_id'");
}
?>
```

Comment: На сервер прийдет то, что находится в инпутах по их названию. Посмотри в браузере что уходит на сервер. В твоём случае уйдет переменная r. Назначь значения для radio и на сервере получишь их, через переменную r

Comment: @SultanovShamil не совсем понял что конкретно вы имеете ввиду, не могли бы показать?

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего кода вам нужно переименовать `input name` в `r1` и `r2` соответственно.
Либо дописать в `input` атрибут `value = "r1"` и `value = "r2"` соответственно. А в php-коде проверять следующим образом:

```
if (!empty($_POST["r"]) && $_POST["r"] == 'r1')
```

Comment: Поменял на r1/r2, но теперь при выборе сначала первой картинки, а потом второй, с первой зеленый ободок выбора не пропадает, но в БД записывается то что нужно

Comment: @Midnight  по этому, лучшим вариантом будет оставить атрибуты `name` одинаковыми, но дописать атрибут  `value`. В своём ответе я описал как это сделать.